# Returning a tuple column type from slick plain SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

In slick 3 with postgres, I'm trying to use a plain sql query with a tuple column return type. My query is something like this:

```
sql"""
  select (column1, column2) as tup from table group by tup;
""".as[((Int, String))]
```

But at compile time I get the following error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[((Int, String), String)]

How can I return a tuple column type with a plain sql query?

Comment: Does the query work without the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @Dario the issue isn't really the group by, it's the mapping between column type and the scala type. The query runs if you run it right on the database with or without the group by, it doesn't run at all through slick.

Comment: Slick doesn't support composite types out of the box, but there is a Slick extension library for PostgreSQL which does. You can see some examples here: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/68aa4c3d4370fdfe8f26609b2cafac1e620e99d4/src/test/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/PgCompositeSupportSuite.scala#L237

Answer (score 1):

`GetResult[T]` is a wrapper for function `PositionedResult => T` and expects an implicit val with `PositionedResult` methods such as `nextInt`, `nextString` to extract positional typed fields.  The following implicit val should address your need:

```
implicit val getTableResult = GetResult(r => (r.nextInt, r.nextString))
```

More details can be found in this [Slick doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/sql.html#result-sets).